# When Accessing Cookie in .NET Core MVC it showing value as null

Tags: javascript, c#, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc

Edit: resolved used library: here is link: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

I have two cookies in my browser ,   "cartNumbers" with value 2. which I can access in .NET.

But the other cookie which is "productsInCart" with value:

```
[{"slNo":"8","pName":"RAY BAN","pPrice":"8790.00","pQty":1,"image":"https://localhost:44314/Images/13bacad884054b62a37d6840a95b8bd9.jpg"},{"slNo":"21","pName":"GREY T-SHIRT","pPrice":"555.00","pQty":1,"image":"https://localhost:44314/Images/6d80b0a28b94472b959db3f69c65faba.jpg"}]
```

when I try to access productInCart I get 'null'. please help. this is how I'm accessing them both

```
var ProductInCart = Request.Cookies["productsInCart"];             
var CartNumber = Request.Cookies["cartNumbers"];
```

I have created these cookies in javaScript and  i'm trying to acess them in .NET MVC controller

my javaScript code

```
    function setCookie(name, value, exp_days) {
        let d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + exp_days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // calling setTime() method
        let expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
    }
    
    
    function getCookie(key) {
        let keyValue = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + key + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
        return keyValue ? keyValue[2] : null;
    }

$("#addtocart").click(function () {
    const product = document.getElementById('product-name').innerText;
    const price = document.getElementById('product-price').innerText;
    const img = document.querySelector('#product-image').src;
    let quantity = parseInt($('#quantity').find(":selected").text());
    let pId = params.get('id');


    let key = "productsInCart";
    if (getCookie(key)) {
        const data = JSON.parse(getCookie(key));

        let curObj = { "slNo": pId, "pName": product, "pPrice": price, "pQty": quantity, "image": img };

        addItemToCart(data, pId, quantity, curObj);

        let value = JSON.stringify(data);
        setCookie(key, value, 90);
    }
    else {
        cartdata.push({ "slNo": pId, "pName": product, "pPrice": price, "pQty": quantity, "image": img });
        let value = JSON.stringify(cartdata);
        setCookie(key, value, 90);
        
    }

    toastr.success('product Sucessfully', 'Added', { timeOut: 2500 });
});

function addItemToCart(data, pId, quantity, curObj) {
    for (let obj of data) {
        if (obj.slNo === pId) {
            obj.pQty = quantity;
            return;
        }
}
```

data.push(curObj);
}

Comment: How did you write cookies to the browser?

Comment: using javaScript

Comment: Can you share that code please?

Comment: it is showing too long I can't post it here. completely

Comment: I have added the JavaScript code please check help me you can

Comment: do you see your cookies in the request from browser to client?(in network tab in devtools)